# subsetting a data frame inside of a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, subset, na

I have a list of 2 data frames' names contained in a vector `df_list`.
I want to replace each NA observation inside each one of these data frames with 0. The number of data frames doesn't have to be 2, just in this case it is 2.

I have tried different combinations of `eval()` and `assign()` but can't seem to get this to work. Ideally I would want to do something like this:

```
df_cnt_list <- df_list[which((grepl(".*cnt.*", df_list, ignore.case = T )))]
for(df in df_cnt_list){
  df[is.na(df)] <- 0
}
```

But that doesn't work (and also all the `eval()` and `assign()` combinations I have tried). Help.

Comment: Put the actual data.frames in a list (not just their names) and run `lapply` over that list.

Comment: @docendodiscimus but I want the original data frames changed and not the copies of them that in the list.

Comment: Your question is the best example of why you should keep them in a list

Comment: Can you show me an example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method will return individual data frames.  It still does the work using a list though.

Generate data:

```
cars <- mtcars
swiss_df <- swiss

mtcars_remove_rows <- sample(1:nrow(cars),round(nrow(cars)/10,digits=0),replace=F)
mtcars_remove_cols <- sample(1:ncol(cars),round(ncol(cars)/10,digits=0),replace=F)

for (i in 1:length(mtcars_remove_cols)) {
  for (j in 1:length(mtcars_remove_rows)) {
    #print (paste0(i,",",j))
    #print(cars[mtcars_remove_rows[j],mtcars_remove_cols[i]])
    cars[mtcars_remove_rows[j],mtcars_remove_cols[i]]<- NA

  }
}

swiss_df_remove_rows <- sample(1:nrow(swiss_df),round(nrow(swiss_df)/10,digits=0),replace=F)
swiss_df_remove_cols <- sample(1:ncol(swiss_df),round(ncol(swiss_df)/10,digits=0),replace=F)

for (i in 1:length(swiss_df_remove_cols)) {
  for (j in 1:length(swiss_df_remove_rows)) {
    #print (paste0(i,",",j))
    #print(swiss_df[swiss_df_remove_rows[j],swiss_df_remove_cols[i]])
    swiss_df[swiss_df_remove_rows[j],swiss_df_remove_cols[i]]<- NA

  }
}
```

Change NAs to 0:

```
df_list <- list(cars=cars,swiss_df=swiss_df)

df_list_2 <- lapply(df_list, function(x) {


  x[is.na(x)] <- 0
  return(x)
  #print(x)
  #i=i+1

  }
  )

rm(cars,swiss_df)
gc()

lapply(names(df_list_2), function(x) assign(x, df_list_2[[x]], envir = .GlobalEnv))
```

Answer (score 0):

For a given data frame `df`, you can set the NA values to 0 using:

```
df[which(is.na(df), arr.ind=TRUE)] <- 0
```

If you had a list of data frames, e.g. `list_of_df <- list(df1, df2)`, you can change the values in each data frame using a `for` loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(list_of_df)) {
  list_of_df[[i]][which(is.na(list_of_df[[i]]), arr.ind=TRUE)] <- 0
}
```

or using `lapply`:

```
list_of_df <- lapply(list_of_df, function (df) {
  df[which(is.na(df), arr.ind=TRUE)] <- 0
  df
})
```